# C++ can't modify private variable with setter in a class of class

Tags: c++, class, methods, graph, private

I know that setter functions are basic in C++, but I can't seem to create one properly.

I have a class, `Graph`, that contains another class, `Vertex`.
In `main`, I instantiate an object of type `Graph` and use that object to read a file that adds objects of type `Vertex` to the `Graph`.

The problem is that, afterwards when I attempt to print out my `Graph` object, everything appears to be empty. I think I'm misusing pointers or references.

Could you explain my why I have 6 `Vertex` objects, but they're all empty? (I tried to change my `vector` of `Vertex` to `vector*` but that didn't solve my problem, I think I lost the `Vertex` objects anyway...)?

**Main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Graph g = Graph();
    g.readDotFile("graph.dot");
    std::cout << g << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Graph.hpp**

```
class Graph{

private:
    class Vertex{

    public:
        Vertex();
        Vertex(std::string name);
        Vertex(Vertex const& v);
        ~Vertex();
        const std::string& getIdVertex()const;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Vertex const& v);
        void printVertex(std::ostream &os)const;
        void setStartToStart(const std::string& name);

    private:
        std::string idVertex;
        std::vector<std::string> startToStart;

    };

public:
    Graph();
    void readDotFile(std::string dotFile); // Graph from a dot file
    Graph(Graph const& g);
    ~Graph();
    void addVertex(Vertex& v);
    void addEdge(int typeOfEdge, std::string name1, std::string name2);
    const std::vector<Graph::Vertex>& getVertices()const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Graph const& g);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Vertex const& v);
    void printGraph(std::ostream &os)const;
private:
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
};
```

**Graph.cpp**

```
#include "graph.hpp"  

Graph::Vertex::Vertex(){}
Graph::Vertex::Vertex(std::string name){
    idVertex = name;

}
Graph::Vertex::Vertex(Graph::Vertex const& v){}
Graph::Vertex::~Vertex(){}

const std::string& Graph::Vertex::getIdVertex()const{ return idVertex; }


void Graph::Vertex::setStartToStart(const std::string& v){
    startToStart.push_back(v);
}
Graph::Graph(){} 
Graph::Graph(Graph const& g){}   
Graph::~Graph(){}
const std::vector<Graph::Vertex>& Graph::getVertices()const{ return vertices; }

void Graph::readDotFile(std::string file){
    std::ifstream dotFileIn(file.c_str());

    std::string line;
    while (getline(dotFileIn, line)){
            // Read the file, the problem don't come from here, I just don't show the code
        addEdge(1, "origin", "destination");
        }
    }
}

void Graph::addVertex(Graph::Vertex& v){ // Before create, verify the vertex does not exist
    vertices.push_back(v);    
}

void Graph::addEdge(int typeOfEdge, std::string name1, std::string name2){
    Graph::Vertex v1 = Graph::Vertex(name1);
    addVertex(v1);
    Graph::Vertex v2 = Graph::Vertex(name2);
    addVertex(v2);
    v1.setStartToStart(name2);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Graph const& g)
{
    g.printGraph(os);
    return os;
}

void Graph::printGraph(std::ostream &os)const{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); ++i){
        vertices[i].printVertex(os);
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Graph::Vertex const& v)
{
    v.printVertex(os);
    return os;
}

void Graph::Vertex::printVertex(std::ostream &os)const{
    os << " vertex : " << idVertex << "\t";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < startToStart.size(); ++i){
        os << "startToStart: " << startToStart[i] << "\t";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It just that I have nothing in my objects. When I print my graph I have :
6Vertex :
Vertex: (->But nothing here, it don't show my vertex id or my list of edges)
My set function or my link between class Graph and class Vertex is wrong

Comment: I would not expect any help unless you significantly reduce the size of the posted code. Remove anything unnecessary, simplify and then show us simpler code. Maybe even in the process you will find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `addVertex(v1);` will add a **copy** of `v1` to your `vertices` member vector, because this is what `vector::push_back` do. Then you go on modifying `v1` (the original), but this changes will not reflect on your member variable (same for `v2`). You should move the two call to `addVertex` at the end of the `addEdge` function.

Comment: Just calling `addVertex` after (and not before) the changes will do. Pointers would add complication.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I did't know that vector copy the object, I thought it "just" add the object to the vector

Comment: Ah, and since you are not going to use pointers, you can delete all your constructors and destructors, thereby solving the problems pointed out by Peter.

Comment: That's ok, the problem come from my constructor and the call of addVertex(). Thanks

Comment: You also have an extra brace after `addEdge` int the `readDotFile` function

Comment: Thanks, but that not the problem, on my computer I have no error, it's just on this website, the first person who answer ask me to simplify the code so I delete some part, and maybe forgot some characters, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Your `Graph` class defines constructors with empty bodies, so these leave the members default initialised.

The line in `main()`

```
Graph g = Graph();
```

creates a default constructed `Graph` (temporarily) using the default constructor.  It then uses the copy constructor to copy that temporary into `g`.

Both the default constructor and the copy constructor for `Graph` leave the objects default initialised.

The solution is to ensure ALL constructors appropriately initialise the objects they are creating, rather than assuming values will be copied over.

(The above assumes no compiler optimisation, such as eliding temporaries).

Comment: "Your Graph class defines constructors with empty bodies, so these leave the members uninitialised." - this is untrue. Unless I missed something all members have default constructors, so they do not need to be explicitly initialised.

Comment: You obviously have not even bothered to read the code Wojtek.  For example, the definition of two of the constructors of `Graph` are  `Graph::Graph(){}` and `Graph::Graph(Graph const& g){}`. These do exactly as I describe.   All of the classes have similar constructors.

Comment: `Graph::Graph(){}` is OK, as long as the `Graph()` class only contain a `vector` which is automatically initialized on creation. The problem of the copy-ctor is that it won't copy anything but just create an empty object, but it will still be initialized and safely usable.

Comment: Okay - changed the word "uninitialised" to "default initialised".   Default construction when copying will cause changed values to be lost.

Comment: @Peter ok you are right about copy constructor. Still I would modify the answer even more, since the members are initialised - just in the copy constructor not in expected way. So there is no undefined behaviour.